# start up tomcat from ant script

Tags: tomcat, ant, hudson, jenkins

i'm using the following ANT script to run tomcat:

```
<macrodef name="start-tomcat">
        <sequential>
            <exec executable="/bin/sh" >
                <arg value="-c" />
                <arg value='${tomcat.bin.dir}/startup.sh -Xms128M -Xmx512M' />
            </exec>
        </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

when i run the tomcat startup script from shell, tomcat starts normally and I see an output like this:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /u/app
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /u/app/3rdparty/apache-tomcat-6.0.33
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /u/app/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jre1.6.0_13
Using CLASSPATH:       /u/app/3rdparty/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

I have two problems:

1. How can I tell ant to show me output like the above ? ant only shows me output when there is error.
2. When i'm running the build.xml file from shell with ant executable tomcat does start up. when running the build file through a CI server - specifically Jenkins (Hudson) tomcat DOESN'T starts up.

I'm finding it hard to understand how to use the `<exec>`  task to run shell scripts, is there anything i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Comment: I have found the reason for problem number 2. apparently, when jenkins finishes the job it sends a kill signal to the build  and to all the child processes and thus `startup.sh` terminates before it can even do any job. I'm looking for a way to make the tomcat process stay after the build is finished. has to do with sending a `nohup` signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem had to do with Jenkins feature called `ProcessTreeKiller` described [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/ProcessTreeKiller).

Basically Jenkins automatically kills all processes spawned by a job by searching the process tree for processes with specific environment variable

All i had to do was to overwrite jenkins env variable called `BUILD ID`  and it worked.
I used a [Setenv Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Setenv+Plugin) to set the env var specific for the build.

Answer (score 1):

What about executing the command like this :

```
<exec executable="bash" >
            <arg value="-c" />
            <arg value='nohup ${tomcat.bin.dir}/startup.sh -Xms128M -Xmx512M &' />
</exec>
```

Comment: could work, haven't tried it because i already found a different solution, thanks.

Comment: @michael Well maybe you should answer your own question and then vote it as answered? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is how you can stop tomcat from Ant script:
```

### build.properties file:

```
 #----------------------------------------------------
 #Tomcat Configuration
 #----------------------------------------------------
 #Back-end Tomcat 
 tomcat.dir=${branch.dir}/../tomcat
 tomcat.bin.dir=${tomcat.dir}/bin
 tomcat.bootstrap.jar=${tomcat.bin.dir}/bootstrap.jar
 tomcat.jvmarg=-Dcatalina.home
```

### loadproperties file

```
 <property file="${basedir}/build.properties" />

<!-- Stop tomcat -->
<target name="stop-tomcat" description="Stops back-end tomcat server" depends="prepare">
    <java jar="${tomcat.bootstrap.jar}" fork="true" spawn="false">
        <jvmarg value="${tomcat.jvmarg}=${tomcat.dir}" />
        <arg line="${arg.stop}" />
    </java>
    <echo>+---------------------------------+</echo>
    <echo>|   T O M C A T   S T O P P E D   |</echo>
    <echo>+---------------------------------+</echo>
</target>

Also I have added an element called spawn set to "false", which print execution output onto console. 

Hope this helps :)
```